# How to read from file to stream and display as text?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memorystream

I am reading a text file through a web service.  I am getting the data in chunks of byte[] data and reassembling it into a MemoryStream.  Now I am trying to figure out how to display the text data in a textarea.  Any recommendations on how to do this, I'm stuck?

**Update**

Here is the final solution that returns the contents of the text file as a string which is then displayed in the textarea.

```
    public string DownloadFile(string filenamepath)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        int chunkSize = 16000;
        string filecontents = string.Empty;

        using (var wsc = new WebServiceClient())
        {
            using (var fs = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var buffer = wsc.DownloadFile(filenamepath, offset, chunkSize);
                    int read = buffer.Length;
                    if (read <= 0)
                        break;

                    fs.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    offset += read;
                }

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    filecontents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return filecontents;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
MemoryStream stream = ... //Your memory stream here

using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    textArea.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap a `StreamReader` around that `MemoryStream` and call the reader's `ReadToEnd()` method.

Make sure to set the reader's encoding accordingly.